# Why cannot the Entity Data Model Wizard work for many-many related tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have database with 3 tables as follows:

[image]

From within Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I create  an EF model using Entity Data Model Wizard. I select the 3 tables. Unfortunately, the resulting EF model does not contain the junction table, i.e., `QuestionsTags` table. The following figure shows the EF model diagram.

[image]

My question: Why cannot the Entity Data Model Wizard work for many-many related tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the difference between physical model and conceptual model. In physical model you use junction able to define M:N relation because relation databases don't support it natively. In conceptual model you do not deal with physical storage. Junction table is not included in conceptual model because it is not needed. You don't need to access it, you need to access Tags related to Questions or Questions related to Tags. Those relations are directly accessible by navigation properties.

Junction table will be automatically added to model only if it contains additional columns (not only FKs to build M:N relation). It is also possible to manually modify (EF4) model and force it to add entity for junction table.

Answer (score 2):

It works.  Notice the navigation properties at the bottom of your EF model diagram.

The `QuestionsTags` table only exists to model the many-to-many relationship in a relational database.  When you have objects that don't have to fit into a rigid table schema, you can use a collection on a question object to get all the tags on that question, and likewise, a collection on a tag object to get all the questions with that tag...The Entity Framework models this for you and will populate these collections automatically.